# What is best design of DTO?

Tags: java, spring, jpa

Here's my entity class.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "user")
public class User {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(updatable = false, insertable = false)
    private int id;

    @Column(nullable = false, updatable = false)
    private String name;

    @Column(nullable = false, unique = true, updatable = false)
    private String email;

    @Column(name = "nick_name", nullable = false, unique = true, updatable = false)
    private String nickName;

    @Column(name = "image_url")
    private String imageUrl;

    User() {

    }

    public User(int id, String name, String email, String nickName, String imageUrl) {
        this.name = name;
        this.email = email;
        this.nickName = nickName;
        this.imageUrl = imageUrl;
        this.id = id;
    }

    //getters
}
```

First, I thought that creating separate DTOs based on business logic.
For example,

Named DTO for creating

```
public class CreatingUser {
    private int id;
    private String name;
    private String nickName;
    private String emaial;
    private String imageUrl;

    //getters and setters
}
```

But problem is that it is created many many objects and makes difficult to naming (for example, CreatingUser, CreatingUserWithImage... etc...).
And I may be create many services and convert for dtos.

Now,

```
public class UserDto {
    private int id;
    private String name;
    private String nickName;
    private String email;
    private String imageUrl;

    //getters and setters
}
```

I'm using only one dto, but I think it isn't best way.

Give me any advices.

Comment: Keep single responsibility as your priority and create as many DTOs you want. Because you “must” have to create DTOs as per requirements. Why the confusion?

Comment: many DTOs have same fields, and they require similar convertes and service. it is right?

Answer (score 1):

Best practice for create DTOs is to create DTO for every request coming to your application. for example a DTO for changing password  "ChangingPasswordRequest.java" just has below properties:

```
public class ChangingPasswordRequest {
       private String password;
       private String passwordConfirm;

       //getters and setters
}
```

You can create as many dto as you want and name them as action that they do, like ChangingPasswordRequest.java or EditUserProfileRequest.java or AddWhateverRequest.java

and if some of the DTOs has the same properties(same code) you can use inheritance by parent class and extend it from child classes.